# How to get query string from restify and queryParser

Tags: node.js, query-string, restify

```
var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(plugins.queryParser({mapParams: false}));

server.get('/hello/:name', respond);
```

and invoking this with:
 `curl -is http://localhost:8080/hello/mark?q1=q1s&q2=q2s`

In a function:

```
function respond(req, res, next) {
    res.send('hello ' 
        + req.params.name + ' ' 
        + req.query.q1 + ' ' 
        + req.query.q2 
    );
  next();
}
```

I get the response:
`"hello mark q1s undefined"[1]+  Done                    curl -is http://localhost:8080/hello/mark?q1=q1s`

How can I get the query string `"q1=q1s&q2=q2s"` out of the request?

Thank you

Comment: the ampersand bit me again! At least I get both q1 and q2 if I enclose the command in quotes as below. However, I'm still looking for a way to get the complete query string:

curl -is "http://localhost:8080/hello/mark?q1=q1s&q2=q2s"

Comment: An improvement: req.query gives me an object which I can manipulate to create a query string. Still looking for a more elegant way, though.